# Update ICollection from a IEnumerable in the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity

I have this code in my controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveRecommendedUserDetails(RecommendAFriendViewModel model)
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        Entities.RecommendedUser recommendedUser = new Entities.RecommendedUser();
        recommendedUser.Email = model.Email;
        recommendedUser.Firstname = model.Firstname;
        recommendedUser.Surname = model.Surname;
        recommendedUser.Users_UserId = model.UserId;
        recommendedUser.JobTitle = model.JobTitle;
        recommendedUser.Department = model.Department;
        ICollection<Entities.Group.Group> group;  

        foreach (group in model.Groups)
        {
            //add the goups from my viewmodel to the entity??
        }           

        ZincService.RecommendedUserService.CreateRecommendedUser(recommendedUser);

        return RedirectToAction("RecommendedUsers");
      }
      else
      {
        return View("Index", model);
      }
    }

public class RecommendAFriendViewModel
{
public int UserId { get; set; }

[LocalizedRequired]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
public string Email { get; set; }

[LocalizedRequired]
public string Firstname { get; set; }

[LocalizedRequired]
public string Surname { get; set; }
public string Department { get; set; }
public string JobTitle { get; set; }
public DateTime? DateAndTimeProcessed { get; set; }
public DateTime? DateAndTimeRecommended { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<DataModels.Group.GroupDataModel> Groups { get; set; }


public class RecommendedUser
{
public virtual int RecommendedUserId { get; set; }
public virtual string Firstname { get; set; }
public virtual string Surname { get; set; }
public virtual string Email { get; set; }
public virtual string Department { get; set; }
public virtual string JobTitle { get; set; }
public virtual DateTime? DateAndTimeProcessed { get; set; }
public virtual int Users_UserId { get; set; }
public virtual DateTime? DateAndTimeRecommended { get; set; }
public virtual int AssignedUserId { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Group.Group> Groups { get; set; }

}

namespace Zinc.Entities.Group
```

{
  public class Group
  {
    #region Properties

```
public virtual int GroupId { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual bool IsArchived { get; set; }
public virtual bool IsSegment { get; set; }
public virtual bool AllowFiltering { get; set; }

public virtual string SmallImageUrl { get; set; }
public virtual string MediumImageUrl { get; set; }
public virtual string LargeImageUrl { get; set; }

 private ICollection<RecommendedUser> _groupRecommendedUsers;
public virtual ICollection<RecommendedUser> RecommendedUsers
{
  get
  {
    if (_groupRecommendedUsers == null)
      _groupRecommendedUsers = new List<RecommendedUser>();

    return _groupRecommendedUsers;
  }
  set
  {
    _groupRecommendedUsers = value;
  }
}
```

can some one help please?

Comment: What is the structure of `Entities.Group.Group`?

Comment: You also have to show us `DataModels.Group.GroupDataModel`. But basically on each loop you create an instance of your entity then copy the value of each property of you model to the mapped propery in the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
recommendedUser.group = model.Groups.Select(g => new GroupDataModel { "Initialize fields"})
.ToList();
```

Comment: thanks but i get a red line under the{} part stating Error 43 Cannot initialize type 'Zinc.DataModels.Group.GroupDataModel' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' ?